# Is this the correct way to crop, reproject and resample a raster file?

Tags: r, raster, projection, resampling, terra

I'm working with environmental raster layers from WorldClim V2.1 (30 seconds resolution) in Latin America. I want the layers to be of a precise resolution (50km2 pixel size). However, I'm a bit unsure whether I'm following the correct steps to process the files. Any help on checking the process would be much appreciated.

And one last thing, I'm wondering what is the `terra::resample` doing with `NA`s.
Thanks !

---

Here's an example with average annual temperature

**Libraries**

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
```

**Basemaps**

```
# world and Latin America
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 'medium', returnclass = 'sf')
bbox_Latam_unprojected <- c(xmin=-118.40137, ymin=-55.89170, xmax=-34.80547, ymax= 32.71533)
Latam_unprojected <- world %>% st_crop(bbox_Latam_unprojected)

# equal area projection (Equatorial Lambert azimuthal equal-area) 
equalareaCRS <-  '+proj=laea +lon_0=-73.125 +lat_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
Latam_projected <- sf::st_transform(Latam_unprojected, crs=equalareaCRS)
Latam <- st_union(Latam_projected)

# raster of Latin America to use as template - 50km^2 (50000m^2)
Latam.grid <- st_make_grid(Latam+1000, cellsize = 50000, crs = equalareaCRS) %>% 
  st_sf('geometry' = ., 'occ'= 0) 
r <- rast(res=50000, ext(vect(Latam.grid)), crs=equalareaCRS)
Latam.raster <- terra::rasterize(x = vect(Latam.grid), 
                 y = r, field = 'occ') %>% terra::mask(., vect(Latam))
```

**Environmental layer**

```
# annual temperature files
url <- 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/base/wc2.1_30s_tavg.zip'
download.file(url, destfile='data/wc2.1_30s_tavg')

# average annual temperature
tavg_files <- list.files('data/wc2.1_30s_tavg', '.tif', full.names=TRUE)
world_tavg <- rast(tavg_files)
tavg_unprojected <- crop(world_tavg, ext(Latam_unprojected)+1)
tavg <- project(tavg_unprojected, equalareaCRS, method='near') # reproject to equal area
tavg <- mean(tavg)
names(tavg) <- 'tavg'

# resample to Latam's preferred resolution
tavg_Latam <- terra::resample(tavg, Latam.raster, method='bilinear')
```

**tavg**

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 12512, 11213, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 829.4488, 829.4488  (x, y)
extent      : -5009004, 4291606, -6411068, 3966996  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-73.125 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : tavg.tif 
name        :     tavg 
min value   :  -15.775 
max value   : 29.56667
```

**tavg_Latam**

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 199, 172, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 50000, 50000  (x, y)
extent      : -4409882, 4190118, -6080809, 3869191  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-73.125 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : memory 
name        :      tavg 
min value   : -2.684936 
max value   :  29.17986
```

Cheers,
Flo

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).